# Sitecore Item and media urls with IPs

Tags: hyperlink, sitecore

We have an odd issue with Sitecore in the publishing pipeline. We have some logic that runs during publish pipeline to write data to another system. One of the data attributes that goes through to the new system is URLs for the content and media items.

The urls for items are http://www.example.com/section/abc but urls for media items are going as http://123.456.789.012/~/media/media.ashx. This works fine in our staging and dev environment where the proper urls go through. But in production, the IPs are being sent out for media items. There are no obvious differences in staging and production configs that I can tell.

Any ideas on what might be going on? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be have a look at LinkManager & mediamanager config https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/sitecore-links-with-linkmanager-and-mediamanager/  and this [link](https://sitecorejohn.wordpress.com/2008/11/23/manipulating-sitecore-links/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check what is the value of the `"Media.MediaLinkServerUrl"` setting.

By default it's empty:

```xml
<setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value="" />
```

From what I remember, if:

1. `"Media.MediaLinkServerUrl"` value is not set
2. and `AlwaysIncludeServerUrl` option is used
3. and there is no `HttpContext.Current` (which is true when you're in publishing pipeline)

if 1. 2. and 3. are true, Sitecore generates links to media items with the first host name or ip address that site was hit after app pool was recycled.

It means that if you restart your production server and then hit it with local IP addrress just to make sure it's up and running before it's placed back in load balancer (or maybe it's LB which calls the servers using IP address), Sitecore will generate all the media items url with that IP addrress instead of nice host name.

I assume it works in both dev and staging environments, cause you always hit them with the final host name.

Comment: This does make a lot of sense. But one thing is still not clear. We have the CMs in all environments behind LBs. So why is only production causing this issue. 

Anyways, I've specified MediaLinkServerUrl in code to see if that would make a difference.

Comment: That setting worked in production. But we won't be changing the setting in web.config. We will change this setting as part of media URL options.